# Laravel import excel error Undefined offset: 1

Tags: excel, laravel, import

I tried to import excel to my mySql DB and am facing this error **Undefined offset: 1**

I have search everywhere, no related answers could resolve mine.

Here is my model

public function model(array $row)
    {

```
    return new Medicine([
        'name'     => $row[0],
        'dosage_form' => $row[1],
        'dosage_strength' => $row[2],
        'product_date' => $row[3],
        'expire_date' => $row[4],
        'unit' => $row[5],
        'serial_no' => $row[6],

    ]);
```

my Controller

```
public function import()
{
    Excel::import(new MedicineImport, storage_path('Book1.xlsx'));

    return redirect('Subscriber/importExcel')->with('success', 'All good!');
}
```

[here is my excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHFCi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing a

```php
var_dump($row)
```

and see if all the indices are properly set (especially index 1)?

Comment: Sorry i don't get it! How and where could i put  the var_dump($row) thing.

Comment: Right at the beginning of your model(array $row) method: 
public function model(array $row) {

    var_dump($row); die();
return new Medicine([.........

Comment: okay it's returning an array like this ....

array(7) { [0]=> string(4) "name" [1]=> string(11) "dosage_form" [2]=> string(15) "dosage_strenght" [3]=> string(12) "product_date" [4]=> string(11) "expire_date" [5]=> string(4) "unit" [6]=> string(9) "serial_no" }  what should i do know?

Comment: then probably there is a problem with your file...maybe it has some empty cells. do like this: 'name'  => $row[0] ?? "empty"  for each line where you get values from the $row array. this is the coalesce operator and will assign a default value (the one after ??) if, in your case, the key is not set. then, in you DB, which records have any of the columns populated with "empty" and identify that row in your Excel file. If your DB column is nullable, you can also do  $row[1] ?? null ...for every $row...

Comment: You can even use an empty string after ?? (see below) or null, if your DB columns are nullable. But don't do this debugging stuff in your production environment, but rather on your local vagrant, docker... :)

    return new Medicine([
        'name'     => $row[0] ?? "",
        'dosage_form' => $row[1] ?? "",
        'dosage_strength' => $row[2] ?? "",
        'product_date' => $row[3] ?? "",
        'expire_date' => $row[4] ?? "",
        'unit' => $row[5] ?? "",
        'serial_no' => $row[6] ?? "",

    ]);

Comment: Yeah i tried as you wrote above and its returning an null value, somehow i have figured it out the problem is with the excel file side.

But Alex am facing new problem,  can i ask you on comment?

Comment: So In my medicines table there is User_id column, now when the excel file is imported, my User_id Column is filled by "0" id number.

How can i store the current Auth::user()->id into "user_id" in my medicines table, when uploading the excel file?

Comment: After 'serial_no' => $row[6] ?? null, try adding 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id  I am not familiar with Laravel, but it should be ok, you should have access to the user id if you import the Auth class in the MedicineImport file (e.g. add: 'use Some/Namespace/Auth' at the top of your MedicineImport file, after the namespace declaration ).

Comment: be sure to have the userId property on your Medicine class, as you also have serialNo and the others

Comment: i have checked but still returning 0, how can i get the current user id object in medicineImport model?

Comment: define a property, userId in the MedicineImport class and set it in the __construct($userId) {$this->userId = $userId} Then change to this Excel::import(new MedicineImport(Auth::user()->id), storage_path('Book1.xlsx'));  Then after 'serial_no' => $row[6],  put 'user_id' => $this->userId

Comment: and be sure that Auth::user()->id returns some valid user id; you can use var_dump(Auth::user()->id)

Comment: hey, i did all as you wrote it on above and this **var_dump(Auth::user()->id)** also working fine but, it is not storing to my DB user_id column, it's still storing 0. How can i solve it?

Comment: return new Medicine(.....  -> replace this with $medicine = new Medicine(.....   and then var_dump($medicine)...what's the output? Also, i see that laravel models have a protected $fillable property, which is an array of mass assignable values; be sure that the userId is there.

Comment: it says .... undefine variable $medicine, and my in medicine mode.... protected $fillable = ['name', 'dosage_form', 'dosage_strength', 'product_date', 'expire_date' , 'unit', 'serial_no'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

Comment: add 'user_id' to your $fillable array

Comment: sorry but 'user_id' is not a fillable, it have an auto-increament value isn't it???

Comment: no; it's auto increment in the users table, but not in the medicine table.

Comment: great! then please upvote this as the accepted answer ;) have a good night!

Comment: hey Alex i tried to upvote your answer  but i only have 7 reputation, the system does not allow me to.